# Subversion: detect a renamed folder

Tags: svn, directory, rename, move

This is my situation: I have a local copy of a project checked out from svn. I'm working on a linux server. I perform checkout at the beginning of the working day, then me and other persons edit the files/folders contained in the project. At the end of the day I have to commit changes to svn.

I am using command `svn status .` to get che modifications and then I execute `svn add [filename]` and `svn delete [filename]` for new files/folders and deleted files/folders.

I only have a problem with renamed folders. I know that the correct way to rename a folder in svn is the command `svn move [from-folder] [to-folder]`. 
But what about if someone rename a folder using `mv [from-folder] [to-folder]`?

If I do:

```
svn delete [from-folder]
```

and then

```
svn add [to-folder]
```

i get no error for 'delete command', but get an error for 'add command' saying that "[to-folder] is already under version control".

How can I check if a folder has been renamed? And how can I commit the changes correctly?

Answer (score 5):

You have a couple issues here:

1. You have multiple people sharing a single working copy. This is a bad idea. When you do this, it's too easy for people to step on each others' changes and commit things that aren't ready to be committed. You've lost all accountability - who changed what? Everyone's working on the same files, so now it's impossible to know who did what. Each person should have their own working copy, on their own workstation (or under their own home directory, if you have to work on a remote system).
2. Addendum to the above point: your commit messages describe why you made the change you're committing. If everyone's sharing a working copy, and only one person committing, how are you recording your change history (the "why"s)?
3. You have people not properly using the tools. If you're in a working copy, everything has to be done with `svn` subcommands. Full stop.
4. You're checking out daily? There's no need for that in a proper Subversion workflow.

To answer the core question: 
Use `svn st -u` to look for any changes locally or on the server. It's a good practice to run `svn update` frequently to pick up changes as soon as possible to prevent problems like this, and commit directory structure changes as soon as possible after making them (assuming it doesn't break something else) so that everyone is aware of the changes.

But there is no substitute for good communication between team members and using the tools properly.

Comment: Hi alroc. In my case we do not have multiple people sgaring a working copy, my problem is that I have people not using svn commands on the working copy. On my personal pc I use SmartSVN to manage svn projects: this software can manage with no problems renamed folders. Why I can not do the same with command line svn client?

Comment: When you say "the people" (plural) and "the working copy", I read that as many people to a single WC. The short answer is that SmartSVN *attempts* to solve the problem for you (there may be cases where it can't), whereas the standard client simply doesn't have the feature because the developers probably would rather not expend effort on a feature which more or less guesses at your intent, favoring features which may have less dangerous side effects.

Answer (score 1):

`svn -u status` gives you a list of both local and remote changes, so you will know in advance if there have been any such change.

Also, svn features file locking, so if your team is not able to reach an agreement to not stepping over others' work, this feature can help :). `svn lock [[your file]]` gives you some security, although locks can be stolen. See [the documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html) :)

Comment: Subversion does not implement folder locking, so relying upon it to prevent this sort of situation won't help.

Comment: @alroc Edited my answer. I'm too used to GUI svn clients which lock every file in a "locked" folder/directory... :)

Comment: Thank for your answer. Ok, i know how to get chenges, but how to commit a folder that has been renamed?